# XSL Replace of characters ( )

Tags: xslt

I have a node with some data:

```
<something>Blah blah (Hello World) hihi</something>
```

When I perform an XSLt i am attempting to escape the open and close brackets and can not for the life of me work out how to achieve this so far I am attempting something like this.

```
<xsl:variable name="rb">(</xsl:variable>
<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="replace(something, $rb, concat('\\', $rb))" /</xsl:message>
```

This is the error I am getting using Saxon:

> Error at xsl:template on line 728 column 34 of something.xml:
>     FORX0002: Error at character 1 in regular expression "(": expected ())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name='string'>Blah blah (Hello World) hihi</xsl:variable>

<xsl:message>
  <xsl:value-of select="replace($string, '(\(|\))','\\$1')" />
</xsl:message>
```

This will work for either bracket. Your code is also incomplete. What is something? Does it contain the value you expect? You are missing a > at the end of xsl:value-of.

EDIT : After @Dimitre's comment :

```
<xsl:variable name="rb">(</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name='string'>Blah blah (Hello World) hihi</xsl:variable>

<xsl:message>
  <xsl:value-of select="replace($string, concat('\', $rb), concat('\\', $rb))" />
</xsl:message>
```

The above would have the results you originally wanted, although I see no reason to prefer this over my original solution.

Comment: @_FailedDev: OP's problem is that he cannot specify the string (literally) `"\("` as the third argument. Your solution is a clever workaround, however it doesn't answer the question how to specify that exact string as the third argument of `replace()`.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev You may be right, however if the OP accepted my answer I would assume that he deemed that it did indeed answer his question. Additionally the problem lies at the second argument of the replace() and not at the third.

Comment: @_FailedDev: Yes, but your answer still doesn't explain the problem and doesn't correct the problem -- it is a workaround. I believe my answer is closer to what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 3):

**This works with AltovaXML20011 (XML-SPY)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>  
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="replace(replace(., '\(', '\\(' ), '\)', '\\)' )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<something>Blah blah (Hello World) hihi</something>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
Blah blah \(Hello World\) hihi
```

Comment: "Must be a Saxon Bug." - It works fine in Saxon 9.3 (HE/PE/EE).

Comment: @DevNull: Unfortunately I don't have Saxon 9.x at work, maybe earlier this morning at home I ran something different with Saxon...

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="text">
       <xsl:variable name="tex" select="' blabla ? blabl ?  abla ?  '"/>
       <xsl:element name="text">
           <xsl:value-of select="replace($tex,'\?','.')"/>
       </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: @imran, Thank you for your input however this question was asked over 6 years ago. I will vote to close my own question